# Creating a CSS-rule to work for both a one and two column layout

Tags: html, css, web

This is what I'm trying to do:

[Example http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5761/cssautowidth.th.jpg](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5761/cssautowidth.th.jpg)
([Larger image](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5761/cssautowidth.jpg).)

When the `<nav>` element is present in the design, I want it to look like the example below. Is it possible to do this while the `#content` div has got a percentage value set? I'm just curious to see whether this is possible without using two different styles for the `#content` (both with different width values.)
Just floating doesn't seem to do it.

The reason I want the `#content` to have a percentage value in the first example is because I have a background image in `#body` that creates the illusion of an outer glow.

**Edit**: I just removed the need for using the width percentage by using margins instead.

Answer (score 2):

Check the example here: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0816.htm

What you should do is to set `float:right` and `width` on your `<nav>` element, and leave `#content` without any float or width, just set margin. This way content will try to occupy all given space and wont 'fall' into navigation.

Then, if you hide `<nav>` element, content will automatically resize (but also you will need to remove padding from the right).

This is example code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container { width:700px; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid #000; }
    #nav  { display:none; }
    .double #nav { width:10%; float:right; display:block; }
    #content { margin-right:10%; border-right:1px solid #000; }
</style>

<div id="container" class="double">
    <div id="nav">nav content</div>
    <div id="content">page content</div>
</div>
```

Now, if you removed `class="double"` from container element you will see content is correctly resized to take 90% of given space. If you want to take 100% - just add .double before #content in style.

Comment: Okey, the concept is to don't float the content, and then use margins to constrict the right edge of the box so it doesn't intersect with the `<nav>`. But I still need to have a class attached to set the right margin, right? There isn't a way to get rid of this?

Comment: you could remove margin-right and set height on right navigation so content of #content won't fall under right:float'ed, right navigation block.